# Is it possible to make my system boot if systemd-networkd fails?

Tags: systemd, systemd-networkd

Is it possible to make an interface optional in case it is managed by `systemd-networkd`?

I am using Debian GNU/Linux (unstable) on a Raspberry Pi 2 and I want to make my system continue booting in case no suitable wireless networks can be found.

At the moment the system hangs in that situation and as there is no monitor connected it is hard to change system settings as there is no SSH server available as well.